# Hoeffding-type bound covering all partial sums? (better than naive union bound)

Tags: probability-theory, inequality, martingales

I think this must have been done before, possibly with martingales, but I can't find anything online!

Given $X_1,\dots,X_n$ independent, each $X_i \in [a_i,b_i]$, letting $S_i = \sum_{j=1}^i X_j$, do you know of a good bound of the form
 $$ \Pr\Big[\exists i ~\text{ s.t. }~ \big|S_i - E[S_i]\big| > k\Big] \leq f(k) ? $$

The naive approach would be to separately use a Chernoff bound on each $S_i$, then union bound over all $n$ events. At its worst/roughest, this gives
 $$ \Pr\Big[\exists i ~\text{ s.t. }~ \big|S_i - E[S_i]\big| > k\Big] \leq n e^{-k^2 / \sum_{i=1}^n (b_i-a_i)^2}. $$
You might improve this a little with tweaking, but my intuition is that intuitively, this approach is too conservative because, for instance, given that $|S_n - E[S_n]| \leq k$, it seems very likely that all intermediate $S_i$ are within $k$ of their mean as well.

(Notice that we are not being very demanding: we don't require them to all be multiplicatively close to their means, and we don't require the *averages* $\frac{S_i}{i}$ to all be within some value of their expectation; those situations seem harder than what we want here!)

No approach seems obvious to me (one I thought of trying is to take it term-by-term...?). Any help or references would be great! Thanks!

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%27s_inequality

Comment: @Did, thanks for the link, it's very relevant! That is very close to what I seek. Unfortunately it supposes the $X_i$ have finite *variances* rather than *bounds* and it uses Chebyshev rather than some sort of Chernoff, so it seems too weak for what I have in mind, but I'll check out the techniques!

Comment: Check the links at the bottom, to similar so-called maximal inequalities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like Etemadi's Inequality has what I'm looking for:

$\Pr[\exists i s.t. |S_i - E[S_i]| > 3k] \leq 3 \max_i \Pr[|S_i - E[S_i]| > k] .$

The maximum probability occurs for $i=n$. So here, just use Hoeffding:

$= 6 e^{-k^2 / 2 \sum_i (b_i - a_i)^2}$.